# What does the mw_freegift_product_attribute table do in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to understand how to use the Magento free gift module.

I found the database tables which are related to what I need:

- `salesrule`
- `mw_freegift_salesrule`
- `mw_freegift_product_attribute`

When I create a new shopping cart rule which is related to the `mw_freegift_salesrule` table, it also adds an attribute to `mw_freegift_product_attribute`.

So now I am confused about what `mw_freegift_product_attribute` does, because the column `conditions_serialized` in `mw_freegift_salesrule` also contains that attribute.

Comment: Those are not standard Magento tables, they are created from a custom module from MageWorld. You would be better to direct your question to the people who made the module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-gift.html

Best Tom